# Jinja2 template with extension .html on pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, jinja2

How can I use a jinja2 template with a .html extension in pyramid? 
For instance, I want the view configuration to look like,

```
@view_config(context=MyModel, renderer='templates/index.html')
def home_view(request):
...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
config.add_renderer('.html', 'pyramid_jinja2.renderer_factory')
```

Comment: for 1.5 config.add_jinja2_renderer('.html')

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions:

```py
config.add_jinja2_renderer(".html")
```